# Envoy proxy does not translate my gRPC request to HTTP1.1 request - using the reverse filter bridge

Tags: grpc, envoyproxy

I'm using the `grpc_http1_reverse_bridge_filter` from Envoy to convert my gRPC requests to HTTP1.1. The HTTP1.1 requests will be served by Hoverfly which will have simulations uploaded beforehand.

```
gRPC ---> Envoy (grpc ~~ HTTPS) ---> Hoverfly [HTTP(S)]
```

But, it doesn't seem like Envoy is correctly translating my request to HTTP1.1. From the `server-proxy` logs I see:

```
invalid http2: Remote peer returned unexpected data while we expected SETTINGS frame. Perhaps, peer does not support HTTP/2 properly
```

Is there something I'm missing in my Envoy config?

```
admin:
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 9901
layered_runtime:
  layers:
  - name: disable_apple_dns
    static_layer:
      envoy.restart_features.use_apple_api_for_dns_lookups: false
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 8811
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: AUTO
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          access_log:
          - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service #backend
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                  #grpc: {}
                route:
                  host_rewrite_literal: hoverfly
                  cluster: backend_http_service_hoverfly
                  timeout: 60.00s
          http_filters: # use the reverse bridge filter
          - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_http1_reverse_bridge
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_http1_reverse_bridge.v3.FilterConfig
              content_type: application/json #application/grpc+proto
              withhold_grpc_frames: true
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
  clusters:
  - name: backend_http_service_hoverfly
    type: STRICT_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    typed_extension_protocol_options:
      envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions
        explicit_http_config:
          http2_protocol_options: {}
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: backend_http_service_hoverfly
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address: # Re-route to hoverfly (this is docker alias)
                address: hoverfly #127.0.0.1 #kv-backend-service
                port_value: 8500 #8081
```